# 'mail(): &quot;sendmail_from&quot; not set in php.ini or custom &quot;From:&quot; header missing' error

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm trying to send mail from the localhost using the Xampp server. I changed the php.ini and sendmail.ini files as per the below php.ini file

**php.ini**

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = myGmailId@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myGmailId@gmail.com
auth_password=my-Gmail-Password
force_sender=myGmailId@gmail.com(optional)
```

**mail.php**

```
function db_forgot_password($args){

  $to = $args['email'];  
  $query = "SELECT id FROM tbl_contact WHERE contact = '$to'";
  $result = db_execute($query);
  $contact_id = $result['0']['id'];

  $query = "SELECT user FROM tbl_user_contact WHERE contact = '$contact_id'";
  $result = db_execute($query);
  $user_id = $result['0']['user'];

  if(isset($user_id)){

  $password = 'test123';
  $subject = "Your Recovered Password";

  $query = "SELECT id FROM tbl_login WHERE user = '$user_id'";
  $result = db_execute($query);
  $login_id = $result['0']['id'];

  $query = "UPDATE tbl_login_para SET val = sha1('$password') where para = 1 AND login = '$login_id'";
  $result = db_execute($query);

  $message = "Please use this password to login " . $password;

  if (mail($to,$subject,$message,"From : my@gmail.com")) {
    echo "Email successfully sent to $to_email...";
  } else {
    echo "Email sending failed...";
  }

  succ_return($args);
  }else{
    warn(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, 'email doesn\'t exist');
    fail_return(ERR_UNAVAILABLE_USERS);
  }
}
```

When I executed this API,it gives me

> `<b>Warning</b>:  mail(): &quot;sendmail_from&quot; not set in php.ini
>   or custom &quot;From:&quot; header missing`

How should I resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: After modification in php.ini have you restart your services?

Comment: @HP371 Thank you for reminding,i forgot to id. I restarted the service now and run it again.It gives me ''email sending failed" statement

Comment: $mail->ErrorInfo print error info you should get some clues.

Comment: in from have you added a valid email address

Comment: great. is it working now ?

Comment: @Dharman I didn't get it.could you repeat it again

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Don't store passwords using SHA1. It is useless. Use secure password hashing with `password_hash()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a valid email address when you are sending email from xampp server

Comment: I added a valid email address but still it's not working.I am wondering whether i should give a permission in gmail to access the account from another system

Comment: just add this line in php.ini sendmail_path=F:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe
other than this should be commented

Comment: I have successfully setup everything and it is working for me

Comment: this needs to be done in php.ini https://prnt.sc/q9pbua
this needs to be done in sendmail.ini  https://prnt.sc/q9pcwj
enable this extension in php.ini extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: Email successfully sent